# Query to change all field in a given mysql table?

Tags: mysql, replace

I have a table with a timestamp field called "time".

I have many records in this table and "time" has value like: 1343296642, 1343308689...

I need to run a query to subtract 2 years of time to those value.

Can I do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this UPDATE may do it:

```
UPDATE tablename SET `time` = `time` - INTERVAL 2 YEAR;
```

Comment: I´ll try it....